# каким образом можно установить плавный переход при смене цветов JS

Tags: javascript, css

Цвета меняются через каждую секунду, но можно ли установить плавный переход между цветами, пробовал через transition у элемента css ничего не получилось

```
 html {
   transition: all 1s;
   font-family: 'Open Sans',
   sans-serif; font-size: 10px;
 }


 setInterval(backgr, 1000);
    function backgr(){
      const doc = document.querySelector('html');
      let color1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1);
      let color2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1);
      let color3 = Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1);
      let color4 = Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1);
      let color5 = Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1);
      let color6 = Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1);
      doc.style.background = `radial-gradient(60% 80%, rgba(${color1},${color2},${color3},0.5), rgba(${color4}, ${color5}, ${color6},0.6 ))`

    }
```

Comment: а покажите как с `transition` пробовали)

Comment: `html {
      transition: all 1s;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 10px;
    }`@ThisMan

Comment: надо было в вопрос добавить, а не комментарием

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
setInterval(backgr, 1000);

var flag = true,
    body = document.body,
    pseudo = document.getElementById('pseudo-bg');

function backgr() {
  let color1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
  let color2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
  let color3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
  let color4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
  let color5 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
  let color6 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
  if(flag){
    body.style.background = `radial-gradient(60% 80%, rgba(${color1},${color2},${color3},0.5), rgba(${color4}, ${color5}, ${color6},0.6 ))`;
    pseudo.style.opacity = 0;    
  }else{
    pseudo.style.background = `radial-gradient(60% 80%, rgba(${color1},${color2},${color3},0.5), rgba(${color4}, ${color5}, ${color6},0.6 ))`;
    pseudo.style.opacity = 1;
  }
  flag = !flag;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#pseudo-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition:all .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="pseudo-bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по этому [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6542623/5703133) градиент не поддерживает св-во `transition`

Там же предлагают другие вариант: например наличие нескольких слоев с отдельным градиентом для каждого, анимация будет за счет плавного изменения прозрачности слоя

Answer (score 1):

Сделано на скорую руку, но думаю концепция понятна будет.
Для реализации потребуется GSAP библиотека:

```js
function backgr(){
 return {
  color1: Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1),
  color2: Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1),
  color3: Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1),
  color4: Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1),
  color5: Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1),
  color6: Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1),
 }   
}

createAnimation();
function createAnimation() {
 const tl = new TimelineMax({onComplete: createAnimation})
 .add(changeColor(document.body, 1, backgr()), 0);
}

function changeColor(element, duration, color) {
  return TweenLite.to(element, duration, { 
   backgroundImage: `radial-gradient(60% 80%, 
      rgba(
       ${backgr().color1},
       ${backgr().color2},
       ${backgr().color3}, 0.5
      ), 
      rgba(
       ${backgr().color4}, 
       ${backgr().color5}, 
       ${backgr().color6}, 0.6
      ))` 
  });
}
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Kocta, думаю здесь будет все на порядок плавнее из всего предложенного.